# Javascript: How to store a user generated text in a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, text

I want to have a text field where user can type in some text and I want to store whatever they typed in a javascript variable? How do I do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do that ? Can't you just access your field value when needed ?

Comment: I've several different javascript functions like a function to change the text color, to make the text bold and to add text to my page. Now I need to just add the text to apply these functions on and I want it to be text that the user has submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var userText = document.getElementById("yourTextInputId").value;
```

That will store the value of the element with `id` of "yourTextInputId" in the variable `userText`. You could put this in a function and call it whenever you need to store the value (for example, when a button is clicked, or when the `blur` event is fired).

Here's an example binding a `blur` event to the text input field:

```
document.getElementById("yourTextInputId").onblur = function() { 
    var userText = this.value;
}
```

Comment: How about if I want to use it to append it to a node somewhere on my page?

Comment: `document.getElementById("appendToThis").innerHTML += userText;` will append the text to the end of the element with `id` "appendToThis".

Comment: Whats the difference between using innerHTML and appendChild? Either one would work in this situation am i right?

Comment: If you use `appendChild` you will need to create a new text node using `document.createTextNode(userText)` and then append the new node. `innerHTML` directly accesses/modifies the contents of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_var=document.getElementByID["your_text_box"].value;
```

Comment: That won't work. You need parentheses instead of square brackets, as `getElementById` is a function taking a string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

this is work with me every time try it

```
    function getname(name) {
        name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
        return name;
    }
```

the getname is the function name and you must pass a parameter witch in may case (name) then use

```
    name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
```

to store the value in the variable then return this variable now you have to do call the getname(name) function whenever you need.